# discord.js - Newly added reaction is instantly removed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

[image: Example of reactions for colored roles]

I'm using discord.js version 12.3.1 and am trying to create a system where a user can react to a message and receive a role from it. When you click , you get the 'BLUE' role. If you then click , for example, your  reaction is removed and you get the 'GREEN' role.

The problem is that adding the new role doesn't work consistently. Even when the added role is confirmed to *not* be in the collection of removed roles, the added role is sometimes added to the user and then instantly removed.

Specific lines I believe to be causing the problem:

```
const addRole = guildRoles.find(role => role.name === colorRoles[emojiName])
// addRole: Role (ex. with name 'GREEN')
guildMember.roles.add(addRole)

const removeRoles = guildRoles.filter(role => Object.values(colorRoles).filter(color => color !== colorRoles[emojiName]).includes(role.name))
// removeRoles: Collection of Roles (ex. with names 'BLUE', 'RED', 'YELLOW')
guildMember.roles.remove(removeRoles)

// At this point 'GREEN' is added and removed; all other color roles are removed
```

[Full method with more context on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sjp03RXv)

I can't figure out why the newly added color role sometimes gets instantly removed and would really appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `guildMember.roles.remove(removeRoles)` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). That means it will not be executed synchronized, so we will need to wait until the execution finishes.
We can do that by calling the function with `await`:

```js
const removeRoles = guildRoles.filter(role => Object.values(colorRoles).filter(color => color !== colorRoles[emojiName]).includes(role.name));
await guildMember.roles.remove(removeRoles);

// Find that color's Role name, then add it to the GuildMember
const addRole = guildRoles.find(role => role.name === colorRoles[emojiName]);
await guildMember.roles.add(addRole);
```

I also switched the remove and add the other way around.

Comment: This fixed it but I don't understand why. If the `removeRoles` Collection is verified to not include the `addRole` Role, why do `remove(removeRoles)` and `add(addRole)` need to be awaited? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Matt I took a look at the [official discord.js code](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/1e63f3756e814d6b1a2a9c17af9c2b28ce37e472/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js) and saw that the roles.add function in fact calls the roles.set function. Adding the fact that both the add and remove functions are async, it is possible that the remove function is called later than the add function setting the roles to the previous roles minus the one you want to remove. That is why you had the weird behavior and need to call these functions with await.

Comment: I see now, internally calling `set()` in the add/remove functions was the problem in this kind of situation where `remove()` doesn't wait for BLUE to be added and then sets the roles without it:

    `add()`: Sets the roles to previous (ex. admin) + (BLUE).
    `remove()`: Sets the roles to previous (ex. admin) - (GREEN, RED, YELLOW).

Thanks for checking the code and all the help, I appreciate it.